# Is it good practice to keep variable name intact after performing operations on it?

Tags: javascript, php

Lets say we have a variable that its value is being ready after some steps. Is it better to name variable a new name on each step or stick on initial variable name or even perform all steps at once?

```
$var  = array_map(...);
$var = array_reduce($var,..);
$var = array_filter($var...);
```

Or:

```
$var  = array_map(...);
$sum = array_reduce($var,..);
$result = foo($sum...);
```

PS: Or:

```
$var = foo(array_reduce(array_map(something..)));
```

Comment: Depends on a) readability and b) need for garbage control

Comment: for readability and understanding its way better to leave it, also if you still choose to, you'd have to unset the old variable after every step, because you are declaring always a new one

Comment: Go with the 2nd option. Future you and your colleagues will appreciate that.

Comment: If you don't need the original or subsequent contents of `$var` then reuse it.